# Times New Roman on Android devices

Tags: android, css, webfonts

For my client I'm building an website using the Times New Roman font.

Everything seems to work fine, except for Android devices (mobile, tablet). Android doesn't have a Times New Roman font available. As far as I know you can only use the Droid Serif font, which has a different look than Times. Besides that the font-size also differs and causes a lot of alignment issues.

Is there any way to use Times New Roman for Android? I know about fontface, but there isn't any free webfont available for Times New Roman. Maybe there's an (acceptable)equivalent for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you know `@font-face` (which is the way to go with a web site), the question is just about getting a font for free or finding a sufficiently similar free font. Such questions are off-topic at SO.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a font, but another way/technique to use Times New Roman. Just like @font-face.

Answer (score 3):

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    src: url(LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    src: url(LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    src: url(LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    src: url(LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Download the Liberation Serif .ttf font](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/liberation-serif), unzip and move files to webroot.
you could change the @font-face source urls and move your fonts wherever you want.